# MVC Controller not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to set up a routing controller to intercept get requests for particular files when the browser caches them on app startup. I can see the request in the console coming in:

> Application Cache Progress event (275 of 472) http://mywebsite.com/Path/Whatever/App/Views/SubFolder/Reports/SomeProposal.html

I have my `Global.asax` set up to call `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` (pretty much just OOTB code though):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\tory.waterman\Desktop\app.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("app start fired at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I've confirmed this is actually running and registering my route (I write to a text file with a timestamp):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Reports",
        url: "Path/Whatever/App/Views/SubFolder/Reports/{report}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Reports",
            action = "GetReport"
        }
    );
}
```

(some bits of the path have been changed obviously)

I have a controller named `ReportsController` with a `GetReport()` method I'm expecting to get called:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(string report)
{
    return View();
}
```

But it's never called (I write to a text file like `Global.asax` and `RouteConfig`, but it never happens).

Any ideas how I can get this working or what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 1: Added `string report` parameter to `GetReport`. Still the same issue.

Comment: Most likely the order of your routes is incorrect.  Please show all your MapRoutes code.

Comment: `GetReport` action method doesn't accept any parameters...how is `{report}` from your route supposed to get passed in?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Posted the rest of the code. It's the only route I have defined actually.

Comment: @kaveman I'll add a string parameter to `GetReport` and see what happens.

Comment: Can we see the full Global.asax and the full code for ReportsController?

Comment: The problem is the `.html` (period in the path) try removing it from your request, and I bet it will hit the controller.

Comment: @kaveman That's literally the only thing in `ReportsController` other than the class/namespace declaration. Adding rest of `Application_Start()` code in `Global.asax`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Removed the `.html` from the offline manifest, request came in without `.html`, and the controller was still not fired. Resulted in a 404.

Comment: What version of MVC (3,4,5)?

Comment: Appears to be 4.0 if I'm reading this correctly: `<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>`

Comment: And your controller is public (not internal)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yep, the controller is public.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64962/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-tnw).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I got it -- `Path` is a sub-branch of code and not an actual directory in the application, once I changed the url to `Whatever/App/....` instead of `Path/Whatever/App/...` it worked! Nothing you guys could have possibly guessed, but thanks so much for chatting with me and trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your route is defined as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Reports",
    url: "Path/Whatever/App/Views/SubFolder/Reports/{report}", //with route param
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Reports",
        action = "GetReport"
    }
);
```

Your action method signature needs a `report` parameter or else the route won't match:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(string report)
{
    return View();
}
```